# Building and Running GTK application on Windows with Meson

Tags: c, windows, windows-10, gtk, gtk3

I am currently unable to successfully run the application I have built successfully using Meson. To install GTK I followed the steps available [here](https://www.gtk.org/download/windows.php) in order to install it. Additionally I added the path `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin` to my path.

Inside of that path, I was able to successfully run the applications `gtk-demo.exe`, `gtk3-demo.exe`, and `gtk3-demo-application.exe` which would indicate to me it installed successfully.

I set out to build the sample application provided in the tutorial for Meson:

```
#include<gtk/gtk.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  GtkWidget *win;
  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
  win = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
  gtk_window_set_title(GTK_WINDOW(win), "Hello there");
  g_signal_connect(win, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(gtk_main_quit), NULL);
  gtk_widget_show(win);
  gtk_main();
}
```

Running `ninja` in my `builddir` I get the following output:

```
[1/1] Linking target test.exe.
LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/-no-undefined'; ignored
LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/-as-needed'; ignored
LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/-start-group'; ignored
LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/luuid'; ignored
LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/-end-group'; ignored
```

Upon running it however, I run into the following error:

> The procedure entry point g_application_get_type could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\Users\me\proj\builddir\test.exe.

Figuring this was a problem caused by stumbling into DLL hell, I checked my path (fine) and I copied over all the gtk dlls I could find in the bin directory into the local builddir. That didn't work either.

I am at a loss - I'd just like to get this to work! What should I try to do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly this was a very hard problem to solve and asking it in a way to get an answer was even harder.

After a few days of pulling what little hair I have left out, I deleted `builddir`, moved the `mingw64`binary path higher up in my environment, and set out rebuilding it.

As it turns out, this seems to be a problem with the clang backend using ninja. Switching the backend to `gcc` (by virtue of moving the `mingw64/bin` folder up) magically fixed the problem, despite me not removing anything from my environment variables.

I really hate magic - but I have no further explanation for this or a reason why `clang` would fail and `gcc` would work. If someone could chime in with an improved answer that would be great. I am not a compiler wizard with regards to the various C/C++ backends.